# If $f(x)=[x] +|1-x|$, find points of discontinuity in $[-1,3]$. $[.]$ is the greatest integer function

Tags: continuity

[image]I picked out the points $-1,0,1,2,3$

Would the end points $-1$ and $3$ be also considered as points of discontinuity?
The answer says $-1$ isn’t but $3$ is

Comment: $|1-x|$ is the absolute value right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $|1-x|$ is continuous everywhere, $f$ is discontinuous in every point where $x \mapsto [x]$ is.

So $-1$ is not a point of discontinuity of $f$ because $x \mapsto [x]$ is continuous from the right in $-1$. But $3$ is a point of discontinuity of $f$ because $x \mapsto [x]$ is not continuous from the left in $3$.

Comment: I checked the graph, and it breaks at $x=-1$. Also the RHL and the LHL dont match

Comment: It breaks, but since the function is defined on $[-1, 3]$, you just have to check what happens at the right of $-1$. The left side doesn't interest you because it is not in the domain of $f$.

Comment: Yes but the function breaks **at** $x=-1$, so that should count right?

Comment: No. It breaks only if you consider it on an interval that contains $-1$ in its interior. Since $-1$ is the left point of the domain on $f$, you just have to check if the limit of $f$ when $x$ tends to $-1$ *from the right* is equal to $f(-1)$.

Comment: For example, the function $x \mapsto [x]$ is continuous on $[-1, 0)$. But it is not continuous on $(-2,0)$ because it is discontinuous at $x=-1$.

Comment: Okay but in that case the function is continuous to the left of 3 as well

Comment: No. For the function $g : x \mapsto [x]$, you have $g(3)=3$ but $g(3-\varepsilon)=2$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$. So $g$ is not continuous from the left at $x=3$. However, $g(-1)=-1$ and $g(-1+\varepsilon)=-1$ for all $\varepsilon$, so $g$ is continuous from the right at $x=-1$.

Comment: I uploaded the graph. It is continuous to the left of 3

Comment: I meant $g(-1+\varepsilon)=-1$ for all $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$. And see the graph, the function is not continuous at $x=3$ : indeed the limit from the left is not equal to the value of the function at the point.

Comment: I get it now, thanks